# setting default text color of all text in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios9, uiappearance

I want to theme my app. I have a tableview which has a default cell that only shows text (not a custom cell).

I want to set the text color using `UIApprearnace`. This is the code i have so far but it does not seem to make any difference.

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UITableViewCell class]]] setTextColor:snackOrangeColor];
```

Comment: Just set the text color in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: can't do it there because i want the user to be able to switch the app between day/night mode. I am trying to use the UIAppearance to resin the whole app when the user toggles between day/night mode. I would hate to create a boolean and check on it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You have no choice really. `UIAppearance` only affects new views, not existing views.

Comment: when you say new views, do you mean views that are going to be added ? @rmaddy

Comment: Also i know that UIAppreance only affect new view. That is why i remove the whole window and re-add it `NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
        for (UIView *view in window.subviews) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            [window addSubview:view];
        }
    }`  This is working for the other components that i am re-skinning